# Passing 2D array from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to pass a 2D array of float values to my C++ plugin in Unity.

On the C++ side I have:

```
 void process_values(float** tab);
```

On the C# side I've got a float[,] and I don't know how to pass it to my c++ plugin.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does it have to be a 2D array? Or can you inline it as a single array (i.e. each row follows the previous in memory)? Passing a single array would be much easier.

Comment: If cannot modify the c++ plugin ... it's something already done by somebody else

Comment: How will it know the column size of the 2d array?

Comment: I call a function before it to initialize and I give the size of the array

Answer (score 0):

For copying data from CLR to native code use Marshall class.

Specifically

```
public static void Copy(
    float[] source,
    int startIndex,
    IntPtr destination,
    int length
)
```

In 2D case, you have to compute the address of subsequent rows yourself.
For each row just add to the destination pointer size of the float times lenght of row.

```
public void process(float[][] input)
{
    unsafe
    {
        // If I know how many sub-arrays I have I can just fix them like this... but I need to handle n-many arrays
        fixed (float* inp0 = input[0], inp1 = input[1] )
        {
            // Create the pointer array and put the pointers to input[0] and input[1] into it
            float*[] inputArray = new float*[2];
            inputArray[0] = inp0;
            inputArray[1] = inp1;
            fixed(float** inputPtr = inputArray)
            {
                // C function signature is someFuction(float** input, int numberOfChannels, int length)
                functionDelegate(inputPtr, 2, input[0].length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example c#:

```
[DllImport("Win32Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "?Save@@YAXPAPAM@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void Save(IntPtr arr);
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            float[][] testA = new float[][] { new float[] { 1.0f, 2.0f }, new float[] { 3.0f, 4.0f } };

                IntPtr initArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8);
                IntPtr arrayAlloc = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float)*4);

                Marshal.WriteInt32(initArray, arrayAlloc.ToInt32());
                Marshal.WriteInt32(initArray+4, arrayAlloc.ToInt32() + 2 * sizeof(float));
                Marshal.Copy(testA[0], 0, arrayAlloc, 2);
                Marshal.Copy(testA[1], 0, arrayAlloc + 2*sizeof(float), 2);

                Save(initArray); // C func call

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(arrayAlloc);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(initArray);

                Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: So what king of variable I've got finaly, array of IntPtr ?

Comment: The intptr is just address of memory to which you want to copy the data. In my option you will have to allocate memory for the array of floats in c++. Then you can copy the data with Marshal.

Comment: Alternatively you can use unsafe code. fixed(float** inputPtr = inputArray)
            {
                // C functionn(float**)
                function(inputPtr);
            }

Comment: @stepandohnal: I'm interested in this too. Could you provide a working example including c# and c++ code?

Comment: working ex can be downloaded from here [link] (http://leteckaposta.co/file/831197442.1/9145702dfd93e1b1f1ea370ce92b1e8d07505b04/en)